# Posting DateTime Values

Tags: javascript, c#, post

I am using a form to post some values to the controller.

Here is js code;

```
$.ajax( {
      type: "POST",
      url: "GetReports",
      data: {
          MacId: $( "#select-definition" ).val(),
          StartDate: $( "#input-start-date" ).val(),
          EndDate: $( "#input-end-date" ).val(),
      },
      dataType: "JSON"
    } )
    .done( function ( result ) {
        console.log( result );
    } )
    .fail( function () {

    } )
    .always( function ( result ) {
        console.log( result );
    } );
  } );
```

Here is HTML;

```
<form id="form-reports" action="" >
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <select class="selectpicker" name="MacId" id="select-definition" required></select>
    </div>
    <div class='col-sm-3'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date'>
                <input type='datetime' id='input-start-date' name="StartDate" class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-sm-3'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date'>
                <input type='datetime'  id='input-end-date' name="EndDate" class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <button class="form-control" type="button" id="button-submit">Done</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is the controller(where I post the form);

```
[HttpPost]
public string GetReports(string MacId, DateTime StartDate, DateTime EndDate)
```

THe error is that;

POST http://localhost:55616/Home/GetReports 500 (Internal Server Error)

I could not figure out the error and the solution,

I am trying to pass the input values to the controller

Note that I am using MVC C# Web Application.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

500 means a server error occurred. Put a breakpoint on the controller action and step through it. It is likely an error with the code in the controller action. If the parameters are incorrect, the MVC engine won't find the action, and return a 401. The fact you are getting a 500 means it is finding the endpoint, it is just throwing an exception inside the code.